# fabric - is there a way to expand shell variables?

Tags: python, fabric

I'm trying to download a file from a remote host, with a remote path depending from a shell variable.

```
>>> with settings(host_string = 'user@server.com'):
    get('$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora')
```

It throws an error:

```
Fatal error: get() encountered an exception while downloading '/home/user/$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora'

Underlying exception:
    No such file
```

Is there a way to ask for shell variable expansion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`fabric.operations.run()`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.5/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.run):

```
from fabric.operations import run

oracle_path = run('echo $ORACLE_PATH', shell=True)

with settings(host_string = 'user@server.com'):
    get(os.path.join(oracle_path, 'network/admin/tnsnames.ora'))
```

Comment: That works ! Little correction anyway: since I'm on Windows, trying to get a file from Unix, `os.path.join` gives me a mixed path `/home/oracleclient/client.x86\network/admin/tnsnames.ora` which is not correct, so I simply used `oracle_path + '/network/admin/tnsnames.ora'` instead.

Comment: @Emmanuel: you could use `posixpath` instead of `os.path` in this case.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't know this one ! Thanks !